# Synonyms Matlab function

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

Ok now I have built this function ins MATLAB but it is not working..Maybe somewhere error exists

Do Guide please...

Code Below

PFA

```
function takesynonyms(words)
%words = {'good'};%, 'bad', 'apple'};

Doc = actxserver('Word.Application');
X = cellfun(@(word) invoke(Doc,'SynonymInfo',word), words, 'UniformOutput', false);
Synonyms = cellfun(@(X) get(X,'MeaningList'), X, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

On main command, I must write takesynonyms(mywords) and it should return me synonyms

normally it works fine but how in function to use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your final results returned from the function, define them as output in the function header:

```
function Synonyms = takesynonyms(words)
```

This way you can call the function and retrieve its output into some variable:

```
goodSynonyms = takesynonyms('good');
```

Read more about defining functions in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).